# std::tuple duplicate type T in get<T>(tuple) - Compile time assertion failure

Tags: c++, windows, c++14, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I am storing the variadic arguments to an object constructor inside a `std::tuple` and so far so good. But when calling an object function using the stored arguments and `std::get<>()`, I will be thrown a **compile-time** assertion failure that I simply don't understand. This will happen **only when all arguments are not each of a different type**.

The compiler error message is:

> msvc\14.16.27023\include\tuple(934): error C2338: duplicate type T in
>   get(tuple)

mcve below:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class... Args>
struct store_in_tuple {

    tuple<Args...> m_tuple_args;

    store_in_tuple(Args... args) : m_tuple_args{ args... } {}

    void func() {
        func_tuple(std::get<Args>(m_tuple_args)...);
    }

    void func_tuple(Args... args) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    store_in_tuple<int, float, double, int> sit1(1, 2.0f, 3.0, 4);
    sit1.func(); // <- not ok

    store_in_tuple<int, float, double, size_t> sit2(1, 2.0f, 3.0, 4);
    sit2.func(); // <- ok

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen and is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [C++17 `std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to pass all the elements of a tuple to a function.

```
std::apply([&](auto... x){ func_tuple(x...); }, m_tuple_args);
```

You insist on staying with C++14?
No problem, cppreference.com shows a short and simple production-quality example-implementation.

Alternatively, you can work directly with [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to get unique indices instead of duplicated types.

Comment: It worked for me using a helper func and `index_sequence_for`. Thanks! I think when using `std::apply` for a class instance method, one has to prepend the actual instance to the tuple so that it becomes the 1st argument to the function/callable - but I couldnt afford that extra copy ;)

Answer (score 3):

The example can be simlpified to the following:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 's', 2);
std::get<int>(t);
```

here, we have a `t` of a type `std::tuple<int, char, int>`. `std::get` can also work with types (alongside indexes), unless you have a duplicate type. `std::get<char>` will work since there is only one `char` in the `t`, but `std::get<int>` will not work, since it does not know *which* `int` to fetch - the `1` or the `2`?

This is what's happening here:

```
void func() {
    func_tuple(std::get<Args>(m_tuple_args)...);
}
```

the `std::get<Args>`, after expansion, will not work if `Args...` contain at least one duplicate type, because it will simply *not know **which** one to fetch*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen [?]

All goes well when the `Args...` types are all differents.

You get an error when types collides.

This is because `std::get<T>(tuple_val)`, where `T` is a type, "Fails to compile unless the tuple has exactly one element of that type" (as you can read in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)). And this seems reasonable to me.

So all goes well with

```
store_in_tuple<int, float, double, size_t>
```

because all types are differents, and you get an error from

```
store_in_tuple<int, float, double, int>
```

because the two calls to `std::get<int>(m_tuple_args)` fail.

> and is there a workaround ?

Use the numeric version of `std::get()`, that is ever available, also when types collides.

The usual way in C++14 pass through an helper function with `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` (or `std::index_sequence_for`).

Seems complicated but it's very simple

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void func_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const)
 { func_tuple(std::get<Is>(m_tuple_args)...); }

void func ()
 { func_helper(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}); }
```

If you can use C++17, you can use `std::apply()` that (I suppose) use `std::index_sequence` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the use of std::index_sequence for me. I don't want to use a helper function tho so I will use C++17's apply or.... you meationed the *numeric version of std::get()*, what does this mean and can I unwrap a parameters pack with it in C++14? Thanks! Edit: just read the doc no need to answer :]

Comment: @PinkTurtle - for "numeric version of `std::get()`" I mean the version of `std::get<>()` that receive a `std::size_t`, instead of a type, as template parameter (cases from (1) to (4) in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get). I don't full understand your following question but you can see the way to unpack a parameter pack in C++11 (and newer versions) is the usual: you can see it in `func_helper()`. The problem, here, is generate the parameter pack of indexes; you need `std::make_index_sequence` or `std::index_sequence_for` (that are almost the same). (continue)

Comment: @PinkTurtle - (continue) Unfortunately `std::index_sequence` are available only starting from C++14 and I don't see a way to generate the index sequence without defining an helper functions. Starting from C++17, you can use `std::apply()` that take care of generate the index sequence and use `std::get<>()`, numeric version.